# Relation between water holding capacity and moisture content

Tags: soil, soil-science, soil-moisture

I would like to know if there is a link between WHC and humidity. I have a compost with a maximum retention capacity of 500 mL/L and a moisture content of 77%. I have about 290g of compost in each container and this compost has a density of 588g/L. Is there any way of knowing from this data what percentage of WHC I have? For example 80% WHC, 20% ... ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think a definitive answer might need a bit more information.  A simplistic interpretation is that you have 77% of the WHC, as 100% humidity would be fully saturated. But  this assumes that the 77% humidity is a calibrated measure of water content (which is not necessarily the case with cheap/simple sensors), and it ignores the fact that the WHC might have taken into account the field capacity of the soil.